# image very small and time to build too short

Tags: kernel

I've performed a kernel building by performing [this map](http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation).

Each step have been all right until the step 9

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX}
```

and no errors occured.

I did default configuration for new options in `make old_config`
and my `.config` has been copied from my current Raspbian with the known command

```
zcat /proc/config.gz > .config
```

So I was very happy.. but.. But after, I've noticed that the image kernel is very small :

```
root@debian:~/kernel/linux/arch/arm/boot# ls -lrt
total 12712
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3137 sept.  4 21:42 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 sept.  4 21:42 bootp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1648 sept.  4 21:42 install.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8920284 sept.  5 00:20 Image
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 sept.  5 00:20 compressed
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4038640 sept.  5 00:20 zImage
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   40960 sept.  5 00:20 dts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 sept.  5 09:40 SAVE
```

the zImage is only 4 MB and the compilation finished only 2h30mn after it began,

No errors at the end and no messages after the last CC <..>.

An explanation ?
I've got to see the log also,

Comment: Was this a cross compilation on another machine?  2h30m doesn't sound unreasonable in that case.  My kernel.img is 4055296 (4 MB).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, effectively, my image is correct, I did this :

```
root@debian:~/kernel/linux/arch/arm/boot# cd /home/root/kernel/tools/mkimage/
root@debian:~/kernel/tools/mkimage# python ./imagetool-uncompressed.py ${KERNEL_SRC}/arch/arm/boot/zImage
```

And I had a `kernel.img` So I think there is no problem with my image :)

PS I noticed that the debian jessie arm compiler is better than the *tools* one, which has been created with update from debian mirrors , It is very convenient so I like debian :)

```
root@debian:~/kernel# cat variables_env.txt
  465  cd /home/root/kernel 
  467  export KERNEL_SRC=$PWD/linux
  BAD  export CCPREFIX=/home/root/kernel/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-
  BAD  export CCPREFIX=/home/root/kernel/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-
  BAD  export CCPREFIX=/home/root/kernel/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-
```

**GOOD  export CCPREFIX=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-**

```
  517  export KERNEL_SRC=/home/root/kernel/linux
  524  export MODULES_TEMP=$PWD/modules
```

Regards,

stef